# plugin container for xulrunner has stopped working

Tags: flash, static, crash, xulrunner

I am using XulRunner with GeckoFX and I can't get flash to work even though I have multiple browsers with working flash installed. I also need to flash plugin to work even if the user has not installed flash on his system. Is there any way to have a "static" version of flash attached to xulrunner ?

I tried putting the entire flash plugin into the "Plugins" folder, I enabled plugins via

```
GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
```

yet flash does not work.

Edit: **Got it to work by disabling visual studio hosting process. But now the XUL Plugin Container crashes when the application closes (If any flash content was loaded).**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Calling `Xpcom.Shutdown();` before exiting resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin-container.exe can be disabled setting the environment variable MOZ_DISABLE_OOP_PLUGINS to 1 before calling Xpcom.Initalize():

```cs
static Main()
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MOZ_DISABLE_OOP_PLUGINS", "1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    ...
    Xpcom.Initalize(...);
}
```